# How to show image and image name without extention

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

In my view i have one `UIimageview` and 4 `UIButton` , I show the images from `NSMutableArray`. How can i show the `UIButton` title as imageview images name without `.png`?I tried with following coding

```
imageary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dear.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"donkey.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"elephant.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"fox.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"giraffe.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"goat.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"buffallo.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bull.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"cow.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"crocodile.jpg"], nil];


 - (NSString *) convertToDisplayName:(NSString *)actual
{
return [actual stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@" "];

}
```

While trying to retrive name using the above method

```
int i=0;
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
       mybutton = (UIButton *)view;
        if(mybutton.tag == 1||mybutton.tag == 2||mybutton.tag == 3||mybutton.tag == 4)
        {

             animage.image=[imageary objectAtIndex:i];
            name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]];
            [mybutton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"current image name :%@",name);
            i++;

        }
    }
   }
```

it showing error

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73f8eb0
```

Please help where i have to correct.

Comment: can you post the code of how your are declaring and adding objects to your imageary?

Comment: @cyberpawn question is not mine :P

Comment: @PratyushaTerli oops! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing UIImage object in that function where as You should maintain the array of image names and pass that image name in this function & by the way you can simply get the name by removing extension by using this method:

```
[actual stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

Here's what you should do

```
imageary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"dear.jpg",@"donkey.jpg",@"elephant.jpg",@"fox.jpg",@"giraffe.jpg",@"goat.jpg",@"buffallo.jpg",@"bull.jpg",@"cow.jpg",@"crocodile.jpg", nil]; // declare array of names not images
 - (NSString *) convertToDisplayName:(NSString *)actual
{
  return [actual stringByDeletingPathExtension]; //return image name without extension
}
```

Than this

```
int i=0;
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
   mybutton = (UIButton *)view;
    if(mybutton.tag == 1||mybutton.tag == 2||mybutton.tag == 3||mybutton.tag == 4)
    {
         i = rand() % [imageary count]; // set random image
         animage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]]; // return image with this name
        name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]];
        [mybutton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"current image name :%@",name);
        i++;

    }
}
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please also specify the reason for down voting!

Comment: its working, what should i do for showing the next image and next set of titles in button by click

Comment: do you want to display image based on button click index? i mean first image for button 1, 2nd image for button 2 and so on... or you want to display a random image on any click!

Comment: random image on any of the button click but one button title should be the imageview images

Comment: than set i to that random image index like i = rand() % [imageary count];, see above edited code!

Comment: but some titles repeating twice.Is it possible  show title without repeating

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]];
```

you are passing in the `UIImage` object to a method that expects an `NSString` object.

You need to pass the filename, not the image.

As a side note - this line:

```
return [actual stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@" "];
```

should be:

```
return [actual stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""];
```

Comment: `UIImage` doesn't have any concept of image name. I assumed you had a separate array of image names associated with your images.

Comment: that is what im asking what the procedure to seperate the name from images in array

Comment: There isn't any way to get the image name from the `UIImage` objects. You need to keep track of the image name some other way. What is "image name" anyway? Where did it come from? Do you mean the filename used to load the image? If that is what you want then you need to track those names yourself.

Comment: Please explain the down vote. How is my answer any less correct than the up voted answer that provides exactly the same information?

Comment: why this answer is down voted ? This sounds like a reasonable answer (+1)

Comment: @MidhunMP i cant down vote,becuase 120 reputation need right?

Comment: @Fazil: ya, you need 125 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems

> [imageary objectAtIndex: i ]

is an

> UIImage

object. Its not an NSString. So you got the exception.

You can make imageary with name of images and you can do like this

> animage.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[imageary objectAtIndex: i ]];

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`NSArray *arr = [[imageary objectAtIndex:indexNo] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
Nsstring *imageName = [arr objectAtIndex:0];`

you can use imageName to set your UIButton title